# Mysql-workbench data base is not connected on eclipse ubuntu

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

I've created a JFrame on eclipse for authetification by a username and a password which i recover them through mysql workbench database, and i have imported the library "jar" of mysql connector java and build it on the project.
**the code is the one given bellow:**

```
pnlBtnlogin.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                String pseudo = txtUsername.getText();
                String mdp= pwd.getText();
                try {
                    
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn =(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/utilisateurs","root","Mrayhana123");
                    Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
                    String sql="select * from etudiant where username='"+pseudo+"' and pwd='"+mdp+"'";
                    ResultSet result = stm.executeQuery(sql);
                    if(result.next()) {
                        lblLoginMessage.setText("vous êtes connecté");
                        lblLoginMessage.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                    }
                    else {
                        lblLoginMessage.setText("Pseudo ou mot de passe incorrect !");
                        lblLoginMessage.setForeground(Color.RED);
                    }
                    
                } catch(Exception e1){
                    System.out.println("not connected to database");
            }
```

**And the result :** not connected to database
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Call `e1.printStacktrace()` in the `catch` to get all the details of what went wrong.

Comment: @greg-449 No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/utilisateurs , i think it because of the JDBC URL format "jdbc:mysql" is not matching with any registered JDBC driver. :/